# Recursively obtain all children from a single parent

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree, children

I have an array of folders, each have a unique ID and a parent ID. What I'm trying to do is find all of the children folders from a parent, even if a child is a sub-sub-folder, or a sub-sub-sub-folder (infinitely). All I need is an array of all of these ID's.

For example if I have the following array

```
$folders = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => null
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'parent' => null
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'parent' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 3
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'parent' => 4
    ],
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'parent' => 1
    ]
];
```

If I want to get all children of folder ID 1, need to be able to loop through and get the following in response:

```
$children = [3,4,5,6];
```

I've tried the following:

```
public function getChildrenIds($folders, $parent_id)
{
    $folderIds = [];
    foreach($folders as $folder) {
        if($folder['parent'] == $parent_id) {
            $folderIds[] = $folder['id'];
        }
    }
    return $folderIds;
}
```

But my question is, how can I make this recusrive?

Comment: Why make this recursive? You already seem to have an optimal solution. Adding recursion only means you could blow the stack if your array is long enough and adds function call overhead. If you want to find sub-sub children, then the current algorithm fails and you need to loop over the input repeatedly until your open set is empty. The problem then is that the structure is flat, so if you want efficient recursive lookup, you'd need to transform the structure first to a tree.

Comment: Because it needs to be recursive otherwise it only gets the first immediate children?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could use a loop to do that too.

Comment: How would this be achieved using a loop?

Comment: The array isn't guaranteed to be perfectly sorted as it's obtained via an API (which I have no control over). So a tree sounds like a good solution and I have tried this previously, however, I didn't have much success as I wasn't sure of the best way of achieving this.

Comment: That's useful info, thanks. How many lookups are you planning to do and how many nodes are in the tree? Will the structure change frequently? If you convert it to a tree, then the search is basically O(n) at worst which is optimal for an n-ary tree, but there is overhead to build it.

Comment: I believe the structure will only really go 4-5 levels deep, with an initial flat array of 30-50 folders. So we're not talking huge numbers, but it does need to be infinite, should this change in the future.

Comment: Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than make it recursive, you can expand the check to check for all of the so far found parent nodes(using `in_array()`.  This makes it a one pass check..

```
public function getChildrenIds($folders, $parent_id)  
{
    // Prime array with parent looking for
    $folderIds = [$parent_id];
    foreach($folders as $folder) {
        // Check if matches any parent so far found
        if( in_array($folder['parent'], $folderIds) ) {
            $folderIds[] = $folder['id'];
        }
    }

    // Remove parent id added at start
    array_shift($folderIds);
    return $folderIds;
}
```

Comment: It's one pass over the parameter array but still quadratic if the tree is degenerate. Also, the logic just fails if the tree isn't pre-sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This version does use recursion, it first arranges the array as just the id as the key and the id as the value (using `array_column()`).

Then as it matches each parent to the id it adds it to a list and then calls itself to add any sub children...

```
public function getChildrenIds($hierarchy, $parent_id)  
{
    $folderIds = [];
    foreach ( $hierarchy as $id => $folder )   {
        if ( $folder == $parent_id )    {
            $folderIds[] = $id;
            $folderIds = array_merge($folderIds, getChildrenIds($hierarchy, $id));
        }
    }

    return $folderIds;
}
```

Forgot to add that the array folders should be converted using...

```
$hierarchy = array_column($folders, 'parent', 'id');
```

to be passed in.

Comment: @ggorlen, not sure what you mean?  This doesn't rely on the sorted list.  I would be interested in your solution.

Comment: @ggorlen - *better to use the $folder["id"] property* - why?

Comment: Since OP has only 30-50 folders, I think this is answer is sufficient. Converting to a tree is premature optimization and is a lot of code. Having said that, I'd still do it iteratively since the recursion and `array_merge` are extra overhead.